# How companies update their packages on Linux server that do not have access to Internet?

Tags: linux, updates

I have a Linux server that hosts an internal web server (apache) and database (MySQL).

I would like to know what's the best option to update the packages (ex: web server) knowing that this server does not have Internet access (but could have if it is the only way to get the updates). Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked this up? https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+update+linux+without+internet

Answer (score 2):

You could employ a private packages repo in a box inside your network, that will retrieve the packages (be able to connect to the internet, that is) and then serve them to your internal network.

A relevant explanation can be found [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/266833/284677).

Another approach that I've seen used in highly secured environments is to retrieve the packages from a computer exposed to the internet, transfer them to the target box by using a USB stick and install/upgrade them from there.

Comment: Instead of USB a data diode might be used in highly secured environments.

Comment: @secfren indeed, but that depends on the environment (military ships, for example, have strictly separated networks so data diodes are not an option)

Comment: Both USB file transfer and data diodes are used in highly secure military infrastructure.